# Executing Java programs through Python

Tags: java, python

How do I do this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438594/how-to-call-java-objects-and-functions-from-cpython

Comment: It doesn't quite sound like a duplicate - it sounds more like they want to execute an entire program, not access functions inside a Java class.

Comment: @Andrew Hare: The accepted answer was "run a Java program from within Python".

Comment: @S.Lott: You are correct!  I guess it is a bit of a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can execute anything you want from Python with the [`os.system()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) function.

> **os.system(command)**
>   Execute the command
>   (a string) in a subshell. This is
>   implemented by calling the Standard C
>   function system, and has the same
>   limitations. Changes to os.environ,
>   sys.stdin, etc. are not reflected in
>   the environment of the executed
>   command.

For more power and flexibility you will want to look at the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module:

> The subprocess module allows you to
>   spawn new processes, connect to their
>   input/output/error pipes, and obtain
>   their return codes.

Comment: os.system unnecessarily invokes the shell. subprocess module is the way to do it in all cases, not just when you want power/flexibility.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, Jython allows you to use Java classes from within Python. It's an alternate way of looking at it that would allow much tighter integration of the Java code.